# How to override the ['search_distance'] in Location: Distance / Proximity Views in a custom module

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

After looking at the [location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module. I couldn't find any way to override the 'search_distance' parameter by creating a custom Form.

dose anyone know how to override this variable by using a custom module? .

I do have a map that is already searching proximity by zip code. it uses php code to determine the  latitude, longitude.

I want to add the 'distance' selectbox next to the zipcode and filter it by (25 miles, 50 miles, 100 miles) like that.

Please note: the below Form for filtering is written in a custom module. so I'm looking for php code.

[image: proximity search by zipcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this.  you need to override the query() method in 'location_views_handler_filter_proximity' handler class for your view.
[This link will help you to understand to override the view handler. you can extend the old class with the custom class that you want to override.](https://www.vardot.com/blog/overriding-views-handlers-drupal-7-boss-356)

I can see the variable get updated with what i wanted now.  below is a sample code that you would use for this kind of a override.

```
    class Yourcustom_class extend location_views_handler_filter_proximity{
    public function query() {

 if(!empty(filter_xss($_REQUEST['dist'])))
            {
                $distquery=  filter_xss($_REQUEST['dist']);
                $this->value['search_distance'] = $distquery;
            }

      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much experience with [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module. This feature is supported out of the box with [Openlayers](https://www.drupal.org/project/openlayers) module. I would recommend checking out that module.

I have done a similar sort of thing for one of my clients. I had to hide the distance fields as they didn't want that. If you view source you can see those fields in HTML.

http://biopetonline.com.au/stores

Comment: Thanks @ashish. I was able to solve this by overriding-views-handler .there is a method (query()) in 'extend location_views_handler_filter_proximity' class in location module. that's where all the query calls happens for distance based calculations. just added the logic in my custom module and that solved the issue